# Обработка ошибок asp.net mvc и поиск по категории

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Привет. Есть такой метод:

```
public ActionResult Category()
    {
        var Categories = DB.Categories;
        string result = "";
        foreach (var category in Categories)
        {
           result += "<li><a href='/Home/Category/?cate_id="+category.Id+ "'><img src = '"+category.image+"' alt = '"+category.name+"'><name>" + category.name+"</name></a></li>";             
        }
        return Content(result);
    }
```

Как перенаправить на мастер страницу пользователя, если он вводит в адресную строку не существующую категорию?

Есть три таблицы Goods, Categories и GoodsCategories.
Последняя связана так -

```
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GoodsCategory] (
    [GoodID]     INT NOT NULL,
    [CategoryID] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [Good_cat_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([GoodID] ASC, [CategoryID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Good] FOREIGN KEY ([GoodID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Goods] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Category] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([Id])
);`(GoodID из таблицы GoodsCategory связан с Id в таблице Goods, также и категории)
```

Стоит ли это всё делать через многие ко многим? Если у одного товара может быть только одна категория

Comment: переадресация https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/3.8.php

Comment: Я понял. Но как составить само условие? if(?)

Comment: проверить возвращает ли модель такую категорию

Comment: напишите что по какому полю ищите , по id или по Name , по чему происходит поиск , что в контроллер то приходит ???

Comment: cate_id(category.Id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int categoryId;
if (int.TryParse(Request["cate_id"], out categoryId) && 
    Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == categoryId) == null))
{
  // redirect
}
```

Comment: if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryId) && Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == categoryId) == null)) - x.Id == categoryId невозможно применить оператор == к string и int, а если конвертировать в int - то выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: @50VAJJ "выдаёт ошибку." - никогда не говорите людям, которые пытаются Вам помочь, какую ошибку Вы получаете. Мы любим гадать!

Comment: Протупил.. System.NotSupportedException: "Выражению LINQ to Entities не удается распознать метод "Int32 Parse(System.String)", поэтому его нельзя преобразовать в выражение хранилища."

Comment: Теперь работает. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

я конечно может туплю , и чего то не понимаю , по идее если адресная строка ведет к методу в контроллере , и метод должен принимать id , если вы ищите что то по id в своей базе данных и выводите это пользователю, то примерно так выглядит

```
 public ActionResult GetAuto(int? id)
    {
        if ((id == null))
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var auto = db.TableAuto.FirstOrDefault((u) => u.Id == id);
        if ((auto == null))
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(auto);
    }
```

а далее уже, создаете вьюху , на основании модели TableAuto , выбрав , например, из списка вариант "Детали" , и получаете готовую страницу для просмотра пользователем , со всем тем , что вы оставите на странице из свойств вашей сущности с Id из запроса  (auto) .
  Возможно лямбды как то не так записаны , C# не мое пока ...

отображать в ретурнах можете все что хотите , то что там сейчас  - как вариант

Comment: Спасибо. А если я использую вариант реализации категорий через промежуточную таблицу (многие ко многим тоесть)? То что нужно изменить? В промежуточной  два поля: goodId и categoryId. Все они связаны.

Comment: напиши что и откуда надо получить , если инфа по моделям и вдруг сложным моделям нужна , я раньше давал ссылку https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/5.1.php , тут все есть у человека ..   
вот тут твои модели https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IvpkJ0KhkXw&list=PLL-k0Ff5RfqXnwdDG61WqZ2j3KXUPnfmq&index=28&t=53s и тут  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNjDvA9HgqA&list=PLL-k0Ff5RfqXnwdDG61WqZ2j3KXUPnfmq&index=29&t=67s

тут весь курс https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLL-k0Ff5RfqXnwdDG61WqZ2j3KXUPnfmq  

я сам учусь , но не в C# ...

Comment: вот прекрасное учебное пособие - полный проект , тут все модели есть , выборки и прочее прочее прочее   
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Спасибо. А вот если у товара может быть только одна категория то многие ко многим не нужны? Достаточно для фильтра двух таблиц?

Comment: друга , примеры своих моделей с описанием приложи к вопросу , изменив его ,   
и попробуй объяснить  что и с чем связываешь , и для чего , тогда возможно , тот кто поймет правильно твой вопрос , тебе ответит ...

Comment: Изменил. Помню в django делал через один ко многим(там sqlite), в asp так же можно?